# Configuration not applied to jacksontester but applied to jackson

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

I'm having an issue using JacksonTester on spring-boot. I don't want to keep null properties on my serialized objects so I set this property on both application.properties and application-test.properties.

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

The issue is that the configuration is working as expected in the default environment but it is not applied in the test environment. Please note that I am using JacksonTester to test my code.

Here is a short sample showing my issue:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@JsonTest
public class PanelistDTOJsonTest {

    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<PanelistDTOOutput> jsonOutput;


    @Test
    public void testSerializeToOutputWithTokenNull() throws Exception {

        PanelistDTOOutput panelist = new PanelistDTOOutput();

        // This test should pass but the property spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null is ignored by JakcsonTester
        assertThat(this.jsonOutput.write(panelist)).doesNotHaveEmptyJsonPathValue("@.token");

    }
}
```

The PanelistDTOOutput is a simple class:

```
public class PanelistDTOOutput  {


private String token;
private String created;
private String id;

public PanelistDTOOutput() {
}



public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}


}
```

The test is not passing with the following error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected a non-empty value at JSON path "@.token" but found: null
```

The JSON that is produced is the following:

```
{"id":null,"created":null,"token":null}
```

Please note that I'm using spring-boot 1.5.4 and jackson 2.9.1.

Comment: Is your test using `application-dev.properties` file?

Comment: I don't have an application-dev.properties file, so to test I added one to test, it did not change anything though.

Comment: Documentation says you should initialize JacksonTester this way:
    JacksonTester.initFields(this, new ObjectMapper()); did you initialize it somewhere ?